# How can I use xcode to edit typescript files?

Tags: angularjs, xcode

I've setup and installed npm, node, and verified they are both there.  I've also worked through the Angular 2 quickstart guide and have compiled and ran the demo app successfully in my mac environment.  However, I can't use Xcode to edit the .ts files.. Xcode is associating the files to quicktime player and refuses to open in the Xcode editor.

MacOS Sierra (vr. 10.12)
Xcode vr. 8.2.1
NPM vr. 4.0.5
node vr. 7.4.0

Am I missing something?

[What I see in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EchPI.png)

Comment: While not a solution to my specific issue.. I found Atom.

Comment: Apparently there needs to be an xclangspec file. I'm looking for the same thing and found this comment https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3404

Comment: @Adam The TypeScript-xclangspec package didn't have any effect with Xcode 12.4.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont't want to install any xclangspec file, then you can change type to other in Identoty and Type inspector (on right side of window).
I changed to javascript and looks great!
But the best solution is the xclangspec of course if exists...